# PHP 5.1.6 Date / DateTime alternatives

Tags: php, datetime

I have the lines:

```
$requestTimeEpoch = 1445857892;
$requestTimeInitial = new DateTime("@$requestTimeEpoch");
$requestTime = $requestTimeInitial -> format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

That i'm using to format an epoch time in the datetime format. The server that i'm uploading to is version 5.1.6, so what I have here isn't actually usable. As the situation stands, I cannot update the php to 5.2+ or add configuration options to allow for the experimental date time. Is there an alternative to these methods that allows me to convert the epoch time into a date format in <= PHP 5.1.6?

Comment: `$requestTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $requestTimeEpoch);`

Comment: sorted, i tried date beforehand but i must've had the parameters wrong, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is,`timestamp` of date and time, use `date()` to convert that.

```
$requestTimeEpoch = 1445857892;
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$requestTimeEpoch);
```

For different format's with `date()`, see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp)

Answer (score 0):

see date formatting in php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php?wb48617274=77D0B224

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$requestTimeEpoch);
```